# How do I find all methods used in solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, dependencies, refactoring

Whats the cleanest way to get a list of methods called from certain assemblies which are in use by a particular VS solution?

I'm about to refactor out interface to our clients code.
We supply a bunch of assemblies with 10s of classes which their C# projects consume.
I want to know if theres a simple solution to getting a list of all the classes/methods being used, so that I can create interfaces.

I've just used the VS2010 Architecture->Generate Dependancy Graph, a useful tool but its doesnt give me a list.

Comment: Removing the reference and building the project will give you a list (errors) for the missing calls :)

Comment: Yes, use **Mono.Cecil** (its author is also a SO contributor)! I never tried it with MS .NET but it should work pretty well and you'll do it with few lines of code.